# What's the equivalent of getSelected() (mootools 1.1)

Tags: select, mootools

In mootools 1.2, getting selected options in a multi select is easy using getSelected:

```
// code 1
$('my_select').getSelected().each(function(opt) { 
    // stuff
});
```

Is there an equivalent of that in mootools 1.1 or do I have to use getChildren() and check whether it has been selected?

What I have at the moment:

```
// code 2
// get all options
$('my_select').getChildren().each(function(g) {
    // if option is selected
    if(g.selected == true)
    {
       // do some stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$('my_select').getSelected() is in 1.2.4 right? Not sure if it's 1.1. if not you can try

```
$$('#my_select option').filter(function(option){ return option.selected; })
```

If filter does not exist, to bad. :( you have to do it manually...

Comment: If i understand correctly, the end result is similar to what I have in code snippet number 2 above. Which is not what I'd expected. I was hoping to get only the selected items without having to loop through each option.

Comment: well, if getSelected is not there. i'm afraid we have no choice. atleast filter returns an array. so you can still chain it to .each